# Lauching Sublime Text From Command Line

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

After following [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907), I cannot launch Sublime Text from command line. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After following [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907) and facing the reported problem, I googled it and realised that I had forgot to create a symbolic link.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl
```

Now the problem is solved :)

Comment: I think it would be better to use [/usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux/8658#8658).

Comment: Do not do this with current versions of ST3 ... its already baked in

Comment: Did not occur for me using ST3, had to manually link. No command line options were available otherwise.

Comment: To launch sublime you need to run `subl` from the Terminal.

Answer (score 42):

For recent versions of Ubuntu and Sublime Text 3, I'm adding a symlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Then I can execute it from terminal like `subl myFile.php`.

Comment: +1 for using [/usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux/8658#8658).

Comment: I was trying to open sublime text 3 using `sublime file.php`. Thanks to point that the correct command is `subl`. It worked without creating the symlink.

Comment: @lev why is it better to use local?

Comment: @wotter check the reply that he linked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux/8658#8658

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is struggling for sublime text 3.

After creating symlink for opening ST3 use :

```
subl .
```

dont use:

```
sublime .
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer creating an alias in `~/.bashrc`, to avoid having to keep track of symbolic links:

```
alias subl=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

Answer (score 2):

for those who install sublime in Ubuntu Software, just type

```
sudo ln -s /snap/sublime-text/38/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: I suggest using the "current" version link, so the command becomes `sudo ln -s /snap/sublime-text/current/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl`

Comment: In Mint 20 I found it in "/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.sublimetext.three/current/active/export/bin/com.sublimetext.three"