# What command to use to open sublime?

Tags: launcher, sublime-text

I've installed sublime in Ubuntu, but I just don't know how to launch it.

Is there any special command to launch it? Please note that I've already read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273034/lauching-sublime-text-from-command-line), but it didn't solved the problem.

I just want to open a blank new file.

Comment: Where did you install sublime text?

Comment: I have no idea, how may I get that? (Iḿ sorry, I'm very, very new with linux)

Comment: Try using this command: `sudo find / -name 'sublime_text'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start sublime from the dash, just write *sublime*. And, depending how you installed sublime either of this will work:

```
sublime-text
```

or

```
subl
```

if you are not sure just type `ls -l $(type subl | awk '{print $3}')` or `ls -l $(type sublime-text | awk '{print $3}')` to know:

```
$ ls -l $(type subl | awk '{print $3}')
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 74 jul  8 07:26 /usr/bin/subl
ls -l $(type sublime-text | awk '{print $3}')
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 jul 19 06:03 /usr/bin/sublime-text -> subl
```

As you can see, the second is just a symbolic link to the first, so it doesn't matter which you run.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command to add sublime to terminal access:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

Then I executed in terminal:

```
sublime app.js
```