# not command 'subl' found, trying to open ~/.bash_profile with it

Tags: bash, sublime-text

NEWBIE QUESTION!!

Hi guys,

I'm trying to open the ~/.bash_profile file I just created with 'subl' command, I created the ~/.bash_profile file using the touch command, as follow:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

it did created it.

now I have to open it like this

```
subl ~/.bash_profile
```

and I get this following error

```
not command 'subl' found, did you mean:
  command 'subs' from package 'libsubtitles-perl' (universe)
  command 'publ' from package 'atfs' (universe)
subl: command not found
```

can you please advise in what to do? I'm really new on this and I haven't found any helpful answer around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lauching Sublime Text From Command Line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/273034/lauching-sublime-text-from-command-line)

Comment: Do you really need to use `subl` (the [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) editor) specifically? Did you actually install it? Otherwise, you should be able to open the file with any standard text editor such as `gedit` or even `nano` instead

Comment: Creating `~/.bash_profile` is not a good idea unless you are sure of it.it will now take precedence over `~/.profile` for login shells..make sure you `source ~/.profile` from it or make necessary modifications..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need your beloved `subl` command in Linux **>;)** and you trust me, than use the three lines below, … If not, you should ignore them.

```
printf "%s\n\t%s\n%s\n" "subl() {" "gedit \"\$@\"" "}" >> .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
subl ~/.bash_profile
```

---

Wise decision, you could also use `gedit` or `nano` instead, both pre-installed on your system. Or install [Sublime 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) or my *favorite* [Atom](https://atom.io/).

*Install Atom*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

*Install Sublime 3*

- 64-bit

  ```
  wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime-text_build-3083_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3083_amd64.deb
  ```
- 32-bit

  ```
  wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime-text_build-3083_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3083_i386.deb
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`subl` is a command in OSX, not Linux.

I would suggest using the simple text editor nano for editing files. The correct command would be:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

If you really need to use `sublime-text` there's a guide to installing it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/582849/InstallingplusSublimeplusTextplus-plusonplusLinuxp). If it's already installed you'd have to make alias files, or symlinks, to use `subl`, which is described near the bottom of the linked article.