# how to open any file on Sublime text editor 3 from terminal ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: sublime-text

I am trying to open a file through terminal but every time it shows an error as

```
No command 'sub1' found
```

Before opening file I have did this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl
```

But same error occuring again and again.

Comment: Are you confusing lower-case letter `l` with digit `1` perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lauching Sublime Text From Command Line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/273034/lauching-sublime-text-from-command-line)

Comment: Did you find that line of code in this thread? http://askubuntu.com/questions/273034/lauching-sublime-text-from-command-line - If so, know that you need to follow the referenced tutorial first: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907 ... if that doesn't work, try logging out & logging back in - that will pull your new command into your path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy the command should be `subl` instead of `sub1`

Btw. A simple Google search would brought you the awnser